# SSRS Matrix with multiple groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, matrix, reporting-services, pivot

I have a dataset which generates results in this.

```
 Parent |   NodeName    |   Value   |   ID  |
---------------------------------------------
AAA     |   Name        |   blah1   |   1   |   
AAA     |   val         |   1       |   1   |
BBB     |   tag         |   tag2    |   2   |
BBB     |   Name        |   blah2   |   2   |
BBB     |   val         |   2       |   2   |
AAA     |   tag         |   tag1    |   1   |
CCC     |   Name        |   blah3   |   3   |
CCC     |   tag         |   tag3    |   3   |
CCC     |   val         |   3       |   3   |       
AAA     |   Name        |   blah4   |   4   |
AAA     |   tag         |   tag4    |   4   |   
AAA     |   val         |   4       |   4   |
```

I would like to group this

```
AAA
-----------------------------------------
    |   Name    |   Val     |   Tag     |
-----------------------------------------
    |   blah1   |   1       |   tag1    |
    |   blah4   |   4       |   tag4    |

BBB
-----------------------------------------
    |   Name    |   Val     |   Tag     |
-----------------------------------------
    |   blah2   |   2       |   tag2    |


CCC
-----------------------------------------
    |   Name    |   Val     |   Tag     |
-----------------------------------------
    |   blah3   |   3       |   tag3    |
```

I have tried some tricks from this link but still no luck. Thanks.
http://agilebi.com/jjames/2010/09/10/how-to-pivot-data-in-ssrs/

I tried what @jimmy8ball suggested in comments. The design surface looked like
[image: Design surface]

The final result looks like
[image: final result. But with gaps]

As I only have three groups AAA, BBB and CCC at the moment. I have created three different datasets with filters to only include one group e.g., AAA.  The result looks like this.

[image: Filtered Data for each parent]

I am not sure if it is the best way of doing. Any suggestions welcome.

Yet another update based on @Jimmy8ball. I am unable to get it working still as per @Jimmy8ball response.

My dataset result looks like this
[image]

My design surface looks like this.
[image]

My result as per @jimmy8ball response looks like this, the second set of values for AAA are missing. Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: ok have you got a parent data item in your dataset? or are you ordering by the name and want to group by the first letter of the name?

Comment: You can accomplish this using three column groups for each field you are pushing out. You can use just deal with the group headers for displaying the values per row.

Comment: These are the columns in my dataset Parent, NodeName, Value.  Yes there is a column Parent.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: In your data, how do you know that the name "blah1" goes with the value of 1?

Comment: @TomH - Good question. I was going to use the order in which they occur.  I can always add a id column.

Comment: create matrix - set the first column as the parent, then drag all other data items on and make sure thay are part of the matrix group under parent - then order by parent in the matrix  - remember to change any of the values in the groupings which will now probably try to sum the vallue, remove the sum and voila, it should be in the desired output as above.

Comment: SQL doesn't have an "order" other than what you express in an 'ORDER BY' clause. Any other ordering that shows up in the data is just by chance. If you want to have a relationship between two rows of data then you need to explicitly include it in the data.

Comment: agreed the way the question reads is that all of the data in the dataset is in a tabular fashion already, for sake of splitting hairs, use the sorting options in the matrix and set it a-z on parent

Comment: @jimmy8ball - Thanks for your response, I will try that and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: @jimmy8ball - I have tried what you have suggested see my question for more details. There were gaps and I do not think there will be a way to avoid them.  Hope I have tried the correct thing. Any suggestions or corrections welcome.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to group by Parent, then ID for the Maxtix Rows, and NodeName for the columns (and Value for the values). It groups the data in the way you need, but the format isn't exactly the same as what you wanted.

[image]

If you want to have the column headers repeat for each Parent, one way is to use an outer List or Tablix for the Grouping.

- In your Matrix, grouping by ID for the rows and NodeName for the columns
- Also create a List, that has Parent as it's row group. (Don't have page breaks between the instances of the group)
- Put the Matrix into the List
- Add a TextBox for the Parent value in the list, above the Matrix.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to update the previous answer, follow the below setup, I have tweaked the matrix to display the NodeName as the split for each Parent, just as before, remove any auto counts or sums

[image]

using row number and partition by here helps maintain the grouping levels, here is the sql i have used

```
select parent+'-'+convert(varchar,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by parent,  nodename order by id)) as parent, nodename, value,  id
from dbo.test1 t
```

Comment: Hi I still seem to not get the result I am looking for. I have updated my question with my outcome based on your response.

Comment: this will be happening because of the groupings on parent, I have tweaked the sql to row number  th parent and this now generates the missing rows for AAA  - can you add this into your script that feeds the data-set -     select parent+'-'+convert(varchar,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by parent, nodename order by id)) as parent, nodename, value,  id
from dbo.test1 t